# How can I disable Twitter Microsoft Translator?

Tags: twitter, microsoft-translator

How can I disable translation link in Twitter? Its really interrupt many things. Actually I never need translation and its taking big space in my browser!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses the Microsoft Translator API to power the translations on their site, however any issues or questions regarding the user interface should be addressed to Twitter directly.